# Jira V6.0+ creating a project over REST API

Tags: api, rest, jira

I've got a problem: I'm working on an external webinterface for my company and we use Atlassians JIRA as a project issue and tracking method. I am trying to connect our webinterface over the REST API. After a short research I found out, that Atlassian never implemented the possibility to create a new JIRA Project over their REST API. Well, that isn't that true, they've implemented it in the actual version (7.0) because they migrated their other two APIs to one REST API. Now comes my problem: We are currently unable to upgrade from version 6.4.4 to version 7.0.0. After a second search I found a workaround for this problem. You can find it [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Creating+a+project+via+REST+based+on+JIRA+Default+Schemes):

The real problem is that this workaround isn't working or I'm doing it wrong.
 I've already tried it with a GET request and the given arguments as parameters and over the normal POST method with a JSON body in it.
What's my problem?

Here some more informations: When I try it over GET, I always receive the normal response for the URL (it returns a list with all available templates). When I try it over POST with a JSON body (this is by the way the normal method for the normal functions of the REST API) I get back a HTTP-Error 415 Unsupported media type.

it would be nice if someone could test this workaround with a 6.0+ version of JIRA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some months I got it by myself. You have to make a POST request with the following header fields:

```
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Authorization=Basic {set your credentials as a Base64-String: "user:password"}
X-Atlassian-Token=nocheck
```

Once done you can set your POST-Parameters to the following:

```
name=Name of the Project
key=Key of the Project
lead=Leader of the Project
keyEdited=true (don't change it!)
projectTemplateWebItemKey=com.atlassian.jira-legacy-project-templates:jira-blank-item (don't change it!)
projectTemplateModuleKey=com.atlassian.jira-legacy-project-templates:jira-blank-item (don't change it!)
```

Hope that this helps someone, Jira is just weird in some cases :/